# Unit testing Camel/RabbitMQ routes issue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I'm having issue **unit testing** a camel route which uses rabbitmq for the broker.

I've been researching for weeks but haven't found an effective way to do this.

Firstly, I was having an issue with **NOT calling rabbitmq** in my test, and to keep this a unit test and not an integration test. This was achieved by using **advicewith** and switch out the queue for mock queues.

However, with the following code the messages are not reaching the result or end queue (MOBILE_QUEUE).

`java.lang.AssertionError: mock://result Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>
Expected :<1> 
Actual   :<0>`

---

Here is my **route**, which imports rabbitmq.class

`from(TEST_QUEUE).to(MOBILE_QUEUE).routeId("test2phone");`

My config **rabbitmq.class**

```
@Component
public class RabbitMQ extends Properties {

    public final String TEST_QUEUE = CreateRabbitMQQueue("TestQueue", "camel");
    public final String MOBILE_QUEUE = CreateRabbitMQQueue("MobileQueue", "camel");

    public static String CreateRabbitMQQueue(String QueueName, String RoutingKey)
    {
        String hostv;
        String portv;
        String username;
        String password;

        hostv = "mq-staging";
        portv = System.getenv("SERVICE_PORT_AMQP");
        username = System.getenv("V_RABBIT_USERNAME");
        password = System.getenv("V_RABBIT_PASSWORD");

        UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromPath("/" )
                .scheme("rabbitmq")
                .host(hostv)
                .port(portv)
                .path("/" + QueueName)
                .queryParam("username",username)
                .queryParam("password", password)
                .queryParam("routingKey",RoutingKey)
                .queryParam("queue","Q" + QueueName);

        return uriBuilder.toUriString();
    }
```

}

And my **unit test**

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@MockEndpoints
@UseAdviceWith
@SpringBootTest
public class RouteTester extends CamelTestSupport {

    String TEST_QUEUE;
    String MOBILE_QUEUE;

    @Autowired
    Routes routes;

    @Autowired
    CamelContext context;

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate template;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        TEST_QUEUE = routes.getTEST_QUEUE();
        MOBILE_QUEUE = routes.getMOBILE_QUEUE();
        context.getRouteDefinition("test2phone").adviceWith(context, new Routes() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                interceptSendToEndpoint(TEST_QUEUE)
                        .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                        .to("mock:testQ");
                interceptSendToEndpoint(MOBILE_QUEUE)
                        .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        });
        context.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() throws Exception {
        String body = "hello123";

        MockEndpoint resultEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("mock:result", MockEndpoint.class);

        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(body);
        template.sendBody(TEST_QUEUE, body);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @After
    public void TearDown() throws Exception {
        context.stop();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interceptSendToEndpoint` is useful to intercepting output endpoint. You probably want **replace** input endpoint and **intercept** output endpoint. See [AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html).

This should work:

```
context.getRouteDefinition("test2phone").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        replaceFromWith("direct:test");
        interceptSendToEndpoint(MOBILE_QUEUE)
            .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
            .to("mock:result");
        }
});
```

And test your route with:

```
template.sendBody("direct:test", body);
```